# In ASP.NET GridView, How make column not show but still get Updated with SqlDataSource

Tags: asp.net

I've got an asp.net GridView that includes a data column that is a secondary key.  When I remove that column from the GridView columns section, update fails because it says that column does not exist.

How can I not show the column and also have the update still work?

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Can you post some code, that would help, are you simply databinding the dataset to the gridview and then getting that dataset afterwards for the update? Lets see how you are doing it boss.

Comment: Yes and thanks @The_Black_Smurf   I was missing the DataKeyNames = "Outlook_ID" field.